# Edit markdown using VScode. When the number of ordered lists exceeds 9, indentation with tab will add an extra space

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

I stumbled upon this problem. I installed the markdown all in one extension and I'm not sure if this is a setup issue with VScode or an extension conflict. See below:

```markdown
1. one
    1. one
2. two
    1. two
3. three
    1. three
4. four
    1. four
5. five
    1. five
6. six
    1. six
7. seven
    1. seven
8. eight
    1. eight
9. nine
    1.  nine
10. ten
    1.  ten
```

After the ninth ordered list, the indented number is followed by an extra space.

I tried adjusting several different Settings in VScode, such as Tab Size, Indentation Size, Detect Indentation, and so on, but nothing worked.

Comment: "_I'm not sure if this is a setup issue with VScode or an extension conflict_" Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: "_When the number of ordered lists exceeds 9, indentation with tab will add an extra space_" indenting _where_ (cursor position) with a tab?

Comment: are you talking by the formatter or in the actual HTML output